# Turn on / off auto-refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, refresh, page-refresh

I have a page that may or may not refresh itself.

And I have a checkbox that will control it, but I have no idea how to implement it.

I've tried to use `<asp:Timer>` component, but it doesn't work.

Using `setInterval` / `setTimeout` from JS, I can't achieve this.

My question is - What .NET component or JS/Jquery attribute I have to use to achieve this?

Comment: You can use javascript setInterval to refresh the page and use clearInterval to clear the interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this if you are using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    
    $('#timercheck').on('change', function () {
       if ($(':checked').length > 0) {
          clearInterval(timer);
       }
    });

    var timer = setInterval(function(){
       window.location.reload();
    },5000);

});
```

Here `#timercheck` is the id of checkbox.

#### [Demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vLsy/)